# I am trying to convert image (PNG) to WA Sticker in my app. How can I do this? Whatsapp supports image/webp.wasticker mime type

Tags: java, android, kotlin, whatsapp, whatsapp-stickers

How can I convert PNG or any image to the Whatsapp sticker format so that I can send it as a sticker and not as image.

Basically, I am making a keyboard app so I need to send stickers to WA from my keyboard but its taking as Image (PNG) and is not supporting webp format

```
private void doCommitContent(@NonNull String description, @NonNull String mimeType,
                                 @NonNull File file) {
        final EditorInfo editorInfo = getCurrentInputEditorInfo();

        // Validate packageName again just in case.
        if (!validatePackageName(editorInfo)) {
            return;
        }

        final Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, AUTHORITY, file);

        final int flag;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 25) {
            flag = InputConnectionCompat.INPUT_CONTENT_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION;
        } else {

            flag = 0;
            try {
                // TODO: Use revokeUriPermission to revoke as needed.
                grantUriPermission(
                        editorInfo.packageName, contentUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.e(TAG, "grantUriPermission failed packageName=" + editorInfo.packageName
                        + " contentUri=" + contentUri, e);
            }
        }

        final InputContentInfoCompat inputContentInfoCompat = new InputContentInfoCompat(
                contentUri,
                new ClipDescription(description, new String[]{mimeType}),
                null /* linkUrl */);
        InputConnectionCompat.commitContent(
                getCurrentInputConnection(), getCurrentInputEditorInfo(), inputContentInfoCompat,
                flag, null);
        getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
        getCurrentInputConnection().sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER));
    }
```

Comment: `Whatsapp sticker format` AND `webp format` ??? Why are you talking about two formats?

Comment: Have find any solution?

Comment: @saiandroid Try converting to webp format or directly send webp format pictures.